# Matrices Equations: is it Okay to Transpose Both Sides?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have this matrices equation:
$$(AX+I)^T=2I$$

Is it possible to transpose both sides to get this?
$$
((AX+I)^T)^T=2(I)^T
\\
AX+I=2I$$
And then
$$AX=I
\\X=A^{-1}
$$

Thank you.

Comment: Its possible. In the last step, $A$ must be invertible.

Comment: It is the first property of [matrix transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your steps are correct ! Your result $X=A^{-1}$ is also correct.

Comment: $A$ must be invertible.

Comment: If all matrices are square, then from $AX=I$ we get that $A$ is invertble !

Comment: It is necessary for $A$ to be invertible for the equation to have a solution indeed. But it is important to note that the equation has no solution if $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: What is your problem ? We have $(AX+I)^T=2I \iff AX=I$. Hence, the equation $(AX+I)^T=2I $ implies that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: You are making the assumption that the equation has a solution in order to conclude that $A$ is invertible. That is all is being said here.